# Why std::numeric_limits::is_integer is false for volatile types?

Tags: c++, std, volatile, numeric-limits

```
std::numeric_limits<volatile int>::is_integer
```

evaluates to 'false'.

But why? Isn't a volatile int still an integer type? I want to know if there is some kind of deep meaning in this.

UPD: Compiler is armcc from Keil 4.72

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90c0f133027cf945), may be it's implementation defined.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: It's `true` with online versions of gcc, clang (with libc++), Intel, MSVC... If you're using an older version of one of these, consider upgrading.

Comment: _"Compiler is armcc from Keil 4.72"_ I wouldn't trust this compiler to be fully standard compliant.

Comment: It wasn't there in the original C++98 standard, but [was added later](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#559).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are (or, may be, your compiler) wrong here because it should be *true*.

From [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) page:

> Additionally, a specialization exists for every cv-qualified version
>   of each arithmetic type, identical to the unqualified specialization,
>   e.g. std::numeric_limits< const int >, std::numeric_limits< volatile
>   int >, and std::numeric_limits< const volatile int > are provided and are
>   equivalent to std::numeric_limits< int >.

And from [numeric_limits/is_integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer) page:

> Standard specializations:
>
> ...
>
> int true
>
> ...

Comment: Hm. That's interesting. Can you please tell me if STL is standardized in any way? As far as I know C++ standard doesn't describe it.

Comment: @Amomum you can check section 18.3.2 "Numeric limits"

Comment: @Amomum stuff beginning with `std::` is part of the C++ Standard

Comment: @Amomum I personally had always assumed that the "**S**tandard Template Library" must indeed be part of a standard...

Comment: @Amomum which C++ standard doesn't describe STL?

Comment: Well, apparently my compiler doesn't follow the standard very well. That's kinda sad.

Comment: Upvoted for the effort of looking it up in the standard :thumbs up:

Answer (score 1):

Well, it doesn't evaluate to `false`, it evaluates to `true`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::numeric_limits<volatile int>::is_integer << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/y3ne6Y

Comment: Why use that dreadful `using namespace std;` if you still type out `std::` afterwards ?

Comment: @Quentin ideone adds it by default. I forgot to remove this line. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: My one qualm with ideone is that terrible behavior.

Comment: that's the least of ideone's problems